# Can you get a parameter from a masked URL?

Tags: javascript

I have a website and it's original url is being masked by another domain. In javascript can I get any parameters from the masked domain?

Original: www.test.user.com

Masked: www.newSite.com

When I do a console.log(window.location.href); I get the Original URL.

What I need to be able to do is get a parameter from the masked URL:

Ex. www.newSite.com/?login=true

Comment: What does "masked" mean? An iframe?

Comment: I think it's like URL forwarding

Comment: you might be able to parse those values from the document.referrer property if the host doesn't scrub it away...

Comment: THAT'S IT! Post as an answer and I will select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. "Masked URL" is a domain registrar code phrase for frames.

Security restrictions prevent you accessing data across frames on different origins.

There are [ways to work around those restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage), but they depend on both sites co-operating, but a frame based domain host won't be.

Get real DNS hosting instead.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't the "masked URL" be extracted by utilizing CNAME since CNAME can point one domain to another?